# Order of matrix when performing multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider that we are given 4 matrices A,B,C and D

So, if I have to find ABCD, would the order of multiplication matter (I would be multiplying adjacent matrices only) ?

Would (AB)(CD) be same as (A(BC))D or A((BC)D)?

Comment: They way you multiply doesn’t matter, they are equal. This property is called associative; please have a look at:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property

Answer (score 2):

$(AB)(CD)$ produces the same answer as $A((BC)D)$.  This fact is referred to as the [associativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Associativity) of matrix multiplication.

As the linked article notes, however, the required number of multiplications is different depending on which way the operation is performed.  For instance, with matrices $A,B,C$ of sizes 10×30, 30×5, 5×60, computing $(AB)C$ is faster than computing $A(BC)$.

Comment: Thank you doctor. Can you please check my question that is very similar to this indeed:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060554/matrix-multiplication-of-ab-cd

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter where you insert the parentheses - matrix multiplication is *associative*. In that sense, the order in which you arrange the calculations does not matter.

Order matters in another sense: $AB \ne BA$ (in general). Matrix multiplication is not *commutative*. That's what mathematicians usually mean when they talk about   "order" in multiplication.

Comment: You mean $AB \ne BA$ Ethan ?

Comment: @Isham Of course. Corrected now. You could have.