# Matrix Multiplication of $(AB) (CD)$

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics

For Matrix Multiplication of $(AB) (CD)$ with dimension of $A_{30\times 10}, B_{10\times 40}, C_{40\times 50}, D_{50\times 30}$, what is the number of multiplications we need for $(AB) (CD)$?

For $(AB)$, we need $30\times10\times40=12000$ multiplications.
For $(CD)$, we need $40\times50\times30=60000$ multiplications.

**Question**: the solution stops and said that the number of multiplications of $(AB) (CD)$ would be 72000, but I guess it should be

For $(AB)$, we need $30\times10\times40=12000$ multiplications.
For $(CD)$, we need $40\times50\times30=60000$ multiplications.
For $(AB)(CD)$, we need $30\times40\times30=36000$ multiplications.

And that the number of multiplications of $(AB) (CD)$ would be $12000+60000+36000=108000$, is not that right?

Comment: What if you do $A(BC)D?$

Comment: I think it’s 30 x 40 x 30 for your last calculation

Comment: @IgorRivin. Thank you. It's 80000 and the shape of matrix is $30\times 30$, which is same as their solution.

Comment: @Avra $30 \times 40 \times 30 = 36,000$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that depends.
Since matrix multiplication is associative, you can get different results.

In your example, there are few different ways of doing the multuplication:

- $((A\times B)\times(C\times D))$:
  $A\times B$ costs $30\cdot 10\cdot 40=12,000$ multiplications and results in a matrix $E_{30\times 40}$
  $C\times D$ costs $40\cdot 50\cdot 30=60,000$ multiplications and results in a matrix $F_{40\times 30}$
  $E\times F$ costs $30\cdot 40\cdot 30=36,000$ multiplications and results in a matrix $G_{30\times 30}$
  so the total cost is $108,000$ multiplications
- $(((A\times B)\times C)\times D)$:
  $A\times B$ costs $30\cdot 10\cdot 40=12,000$ multiplications and results in a matrix $E_{30\times 40}$
  $E\times C$ costs $30\cdot 40\cdot 50=60,000$ multiplications and results in a matrix $F_{30\times 50}$
  $F\times D$ costs $30\cdot 50\cdot 30=45,000$ multiplications and results in a matrix $F_{30\times 30}$
  so the total cost is $117,000$ multiplications
- $(A\times (B\times (C\times D)))$:
  $C\times D$ costs $40\cdot 50\cdot 30=60,000$ multiplications and results in a matrix $E_{40\times 30}$
  $B\times E$ costs $10\cdot 40\cdot 30=12,000$ multiplications and results in a matrix $F_{10\times 30}$
  $A\times F$ costs $30\cdot 10\cdot 30=9,000$ multiplications and results in a matrix $F_{30\times 30}$
  so the total cost is $81,000$ multiplications

There are also $((A \times (B \times C)) \times D)$ and $(A \times ((B \times C) \times D)$

Comment: Thank you. So the solution source mentioned in my question is wrong then.